# How to localize google maps in android, and make search URL accept the argument in a different language

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, localization

i created a autoCompleteFragment search Powered by google on my app, which implements all google maps api.

I am currently residing in Cyprus and i want to test my application. My problem whenever i send the requestURL i get a wierd encoding due to language differences. The Country i am in has the addresses of the location in Turkish not english which when i request the URL the JSON returns with a FATAL EXCEPTION, and my app crashes due to that weird encoding:

How can i fix that? :)
Maybe a way to get the requestURL to send in Turkish?

Many thanks guys, you are the best.

First my method:

```
String requestApi = null;
    try {
        requestApi = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?" +
                "mode=driving&" +
                "transit_routing_preference=less_driving&" +
                "origin=" + currentPosition.latitude + "," + currentPosition.longitude + "&" +
                "destination=" + destination + "&" + "key=" + getResources().getString(R.string.google_direction_api);
        Log.d("TAG", "Current URL is="+requestApi);
        mService.getPath(requestApi)
                .enqueue(new Callback<String>()
```

Here is the weird encoding:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?mode=driving&transit_routing_preference=less_driving&origin=35.3366855,33.27188&destination=+G+i+r+n+e+ +C+d+ +N+o+:+1+,+ +L+e+f+k+o+ş+a+&key="MyGoogleAPIKEY"

instead of being something like this
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?mode=driving&transit_routing_preference=less_driving&origin=35.3366855,33.27188&destination=+G+i+r+n+e+K+a+p+ı+s+ı+L+e+f+k+o+ş+a+&key=](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?mode=driving&transit_routing_preference=less_driving&origin=35.3366855,33.27188&destination=+G+i+r+n+e+K+a+p+%C4%B1+s+%C4%B1+L+e+f+k+o+%C5%9F+a+&key=)"MyGoogleAPIKEY"

Finally, my FATALEXCEPTION

```
07-08 15:02:40.294 29913-29913/com.example.karam.nlgcs D/KARAM: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json? 
mode=driving&transit_routing_preference=less_driving&
origin=35.3366855,33.27188&destination=+G+i+r+n+e+ +C+d+ +N+o+:+1+,+ 
+L+e+f+k+o+ş+a+&key=MYGOOGLEAPIKEY ;)
07-08 15:02:41.042 29913-29913/com.example.karam.nlgcs D/AndroidRuntime: 
Shutting down VM
07-08 15:02:41.043 29913-29913/com.example.karam.nlgcs E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.karam.nlgcs, PID: 29913
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no included points
at 
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Unknown 
Source:8)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds$Builder.build(Unknown 
Source:10)
at com.example.karam.nlgcs.Welcome$4.onResponse(Welcome.java:284)
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run
(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

EDIT
7/10/2018

The suggested encoding for the URL throws an error because google maps doesn't accept Encoded URL strings. i tried to Decode it and removing repetition of special characters by a method, but that does not work either.

EDIT 
7/14/2018
I tried localizing the app and sending the destination variable in a different language and still the same error.

Comment: did you find any solution

Answer (score 0):

[URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) should be the way to go. You can URL encode the text of your destination variable when you create a Directions API URL:

```
requestApi = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?" +
            "mode=driving&" +
            "transit_routing_preference=less_driving&" +
            "origin=" + currentPosition.latitude + "," + currentPosition.longitude + "&" +
            "destination=" + URLEncoder.encode(destination, "UTF-8") + "&" + "key=" + getResources().getString(R.string.google_direction_api);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for trying brother. but it doesn't work, i tried it before :(